# Vlans in Ubuntu 12.04.3 bonding are down after boot

Tags: networking, server, network-bonding

My issue is the following:

I've got two 10 GIG interfaces that i need to use in bonding - LACP - mode 4.
Here is my config:

```
mypc# cat /etc/network/interfaces

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto eth5
iface eth5 inet manual
bond-master bond0

auto bond0
iface bond0 inet manual
    bond-mode 4
    bond-miimon 100
    bond-lacp-rate fast
    mtu 11000
    bond-slaves none

auto bond0.10
    iface bond0.10 inet static
    address 10.0.0.30
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.0.1
    mtu 11000
vlan-raw-device bond0

auto bond0.20
    iface bond0.20 inet static
    address 10.0.1.31
    netmask 255.255.255.0
    gateway 10.0.1.1
    mtu 11000
vlan-raw-device bond0

dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8



mypc# cat /etc/modprobe.d/bonding.conf 

alias bond0 bonding

bonding mode=4 lacp_rate=1 miimon=100 max_bonds=1

probe bonding



mypc# cat /etc/modules

bonding
8021q
```

As you can see from the subject the interfaces bond0.10 and bond0.20 remain DOWN after boot.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problems with roughly the same configuration.  At first, I had some problems with the interface configs- `inet static` instead of `inet manual` on the bond0 interface and `inet manual` instead of `inet static` on the bond0.x interface.

Not sure if sorting that out was the only thing to resolve the issue.  While troubleshooting, I had several instances where the bond0.x interfaces would not come up.  Adding up statements at the end of each interface config section as shown below seemed to help bring the interfaces up, when they did not appear to come up in previous tries.

```
up ifconfig bond0 up ## or bondo.x for each vlan interface
```